# I'm specifying the port when I use scp, but I get an error saying port 22 connection refused. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: networking, ssh, scp

All I want to do is move a file from my laptop to my server.  Both machines have openssh-server installed, and port 2222 is specified in both sshd_config files as well as both ssh_config files.  I'm using the following to attempt to copy the file:

```
scp -P 2222 user1@thenameofmylaptop:file.name user2@[serverIPaddress]:/home/user2/filepath/file.name
```

Even though I have password authentication set to no and rsa keys installed in both directions, it still asks me for a password.  After I give it the password, it gives me the following error:

> ssh: connect to host [IP address of server] port 22: Conection refused

Is there a separate config file for scp?  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to copy between two remote machines, from a third (local) machine? or are you logged into the laptop from which you are trying to copy `file.name`?

Comment: I'm logged in on the laptop from shish I am copying file.name.

Comment: In that case, you don't need the `user@host:/file.name` syntax for the file you're trying to copy - just `scp -P 2222 path/to/local/file.name user2@server:/path/to/file.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `user@host:/path/to/file.name` syntax for the *local* file that you are trying to copy - in fact, doing so is likely causing `scp` to try to open a connection on port 2222 from your laptop to itself. Try just

```
scp -P 2222 path/to/file.name user2@[serverIPaddress]:/home/user2/filepath/file.name
```